# scala x = y = 1

Tags: scala

Как сделать такое присвоение возможным. = возвращает Unit.

Answer (score 3):

```
val x, y = 1
```

Вывод:

```
>>x: Int = 1
>>y: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Фактически, `x` является `Unit` в этом случае::

```
var y = 2
var x = y = 1
```

Может быть прочитан как:

```
var y = 2
var x = (y = 1)
```

и наконец:

```
var x: Unit = ()
```

Вы можете перейти к типу x = y = 1 в оболочке REPL без ошибок:

```
var x:Unit = {}
var y = 0
x = y = 1
```